# Auto Layout with 2 text fields in same line

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I need help with setting AutoLayout constraints for the "First Name" and "Last Name" fields. The "First Name" field needs to take half the row, then the "Last Name" needs to start and take the rest of the row. Every setting i've done, including using Xcode's suggested constraints, ends up with them being offset (to one side or the other). Hoping a brilliant mind out there can help me.

[image]

Comment: It looks correct in the screenshot. What's wrong?

Comment: That's just the view from the storyboard. Sorry...I should have posted it actually running as well. vacawama's response was the solution. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the First Name and Last Name fields to have equal widths.  <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from from First Name field to the Last Name field and choose *Equal Widths* from the pop-up.  Attach the leading edge of First Name to the leading edge of its superview, and attach the trailing edge of Last Name field to the trailing edge of the superview.

Comment: The ctrl-drag was the trick....woohoo!! I had to pin it on top, bottom, left and right, and do the "equal width's" trick. Thanks so much for your help...